# numpy.recfromcsv Transposed Output from CSV File

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have some CSV files that I would be keen to parse with [numpy.recfromcsv](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html?highlight=recfromcsv) in one go with a transposed output where basically the light names become the field names. The reason to do it in one go is that I have a wrapper function above `numpy.recfromcsv` that converts the data to a dict for further usage down the line.

```
Wavelength(nm);380;384;388;392;396;400;404;408;412;416;420;424;428;432;436;440;444;448;452;456;460;464;468;472;476;480;484;488;492;496;500;504;508;512;516;520;524;528;532;536;540;544;548;552;556;560;564;568;572;576;580;584;588;592;596;600;604;608;612;616;620;624;628;632;636;640;644;648;652;656;660;664;668;672;676;680;684;688;692;696;700;704;708;712;716;720;724;728;732;736;740;744;748;752;756;760;764;768;772;776;780
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Spot;0.0649420138;0.0713359985;0.0767221834;0.0828162664;0.0896337031;0.0954200476;0.1015809445;0.1083380365;0.1152099744;0.1226002112;0.1304201937;0.1388171648;0.1474312908;0.1553977485;0.1641032319;0.1729020817;0.1813312407;0.1906956427;0.2004236261;0.2103836711;0.2197347994;0.2301930545;0.2408191448;0.2506142806;0.2611302546;0.2733759514;0.284116684;0.2948628201;0.3056525569;0.3177146507;0.3294133586;0.3397499278;0.3505554406;0.3636232187;0.3766502518;0.3874038118;0.3981092712;0.4107713627;0.4243557832;0.4382433069;0.4498096969;0.461665414;0.4747047349;0.4889017319;0.5024089331;0.5129562103;0.5228344876;0.533534703;0.5462038888;0.5604267305;0.5725309448;0.5825399414;0.5933902825;0.60572004;0.6208132236;0.6357598877;0.6471384375;0.6565189548;0.6650144674;0.6764585843;0.688473714;0.7009057167;0.7127206503;0.7223163747;0.7309630838;0.7397939032;0.751543739;0.7653598803;0.7791136072;0.7895549803;0.7978630925;0.8052200741;0.8125588639;0.8212071113;0.8317661593;0.843195618;0.8515469598;0.8606753344;0.8662945571;0.8712362469;0.8758733751;0.8834956388;0.8940467835;0.9055033544;0.9184418225;0.9269943889;0.9335038181;0.9390080294;0.9393642612;0.9434293798;0.9469191008;0.9500890733;0.9577203179;0.9644588923;0.9720790512;0.9764103807;0.9801371874;0.9839499631;0.9867535093;0.9919074935;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Flood;0.0709192358;0.0780011542;0.0838268275;0.0904401642;0.0978312313;0.1038824584;0.1105203444;0.117754164;0.1248613821;0.1327810298;0.1409765932;0.1496186975;0.1588363439;0.1671464506;0.175832878;0.1850992276;0.1939894234;0.2032968126;0.2131465498;0.2237247224;0.2331370825;0.2432010315;0.2542785682;0.2646114121;0.2748859286;0.2867974914;0.2979924761;0.3093697767;0.3195529647;0.331072474;0.3431973214;0.3542273202;0.3646865813;0.376864611;0.3898278167;0.4015911308;0.4124504414;0.4243576775;0.4370513508;0.4513418047;0.4640631171;0.476030028;0.4880722902;0.5012602469;0.5149219407;0.5266367587;0.5369916948;0.5465622405;0.5575347206;0.5713908865;0.584423412;0.5954682593;0.606238159;0.6171773733;0.6307393028;0.6453821455;0.6576896668;0.6683389517;0.6766358995;0.6866960335;0.6968170975;0.7082208201;0.720769518;0.7318943339;0.7410853258;0.7491866414;0.7591625495;0.7709535145;0.7839377753;0.7949955919;0.8046440567;0.8130366929;0.8198911863;0.8268070804;0.835366696;0.8451332182;0.8532573005;0.8636196782;0.8708370915;0.8764507633;0.8802630265;0.8861248906;0.8946595418;0.9041559755;0.9167776105;0.9261045051;0.9344079806;0.941274279;0.9423009827;0.9450876305;0.9467080756;0.9479125565;0.9538826893;0.9605063968;0.9688127212;0.9747311526;0.9810755784;0.9859659902;0.9887573094;0.9932690683;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Spot;0.0703748707;0.0772490608;0.0822957214;0.0882127866;0.0957963985;0.1021428783;0.1080047715;0.1141684019;0.1214126809;0.1300237476;0.1384609437;0.1459547675;0.1538504992;0.1626621958;0.1728283505;0.1822027482;0.189916872;0.1976659963;0.2068885607;0.2187883328;0.2302677869;0.240198871;0.2483411778;0.2567126052;0.2674389781;0.2809526727;0.2936596139;0.3059000829;0.3147620996;0.3223605547;0.3319088166;0.3442246404;0.3584124133;0.3732600519;0.3856003077;0.3945126405;0.4024199421;0.4118967375;0.4236249755;0.439183328;0.455950324;0.472148459;0.4850815618;0.4948075339;0.5022534351;0.5088242211;0.5186921604;0.5317015467;0.5468822222;0.5635751373;0.578352849;0.5904501179;0.6001563403;0.6067695342;0.613679717;0.622415103;0.6333244952;0.6490413025;0.6648575842;0.6815336875;0.6951308975;0.7058881115;0.7141568509;0.7202305036;0.7243338689;0.7279247354;0.7347784773;0.745966777;0.7611295304;0.7766200518;0.7925236528;0.8079664016;0.8199992547;0.8286494418;0.8347172968;0.8375013496;0.8348916749;0.8360573647;0.8371733167;0.8417985862;0.84996016;0.862369925;0.8776545289;0.8928098123;0.9095353771;0.921835031;0.9318786228;0.9404007037;0.9410916045;0.9409862386;0.9361971456;0.9286087144;0.9235082081;0.9214437767;0.9259588882;0.9330881141;0.9454395063;0.9599214689;0.9724859922;0.9862913247;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Flood;0.0748918629;0.0827435253;0.088379091;0.0941350792;0.1018401903;0.1088519627;0.1157129505;0.1220543146;0.1287878298;0.1376223232;0.1471787969;0.1556335309;0.1633174002;0.171340317;0.1816357849;0.192181883;0.2010292799;0.2088419391;0.2170423328;0.2282683327;0.2402919894;0.2516450482;0.2610049941;0.2689984594;0.2782134044;0.2908451121;0.303998674;0.3175467462;0.3278599948;0.3359702378;0.3441924801;0.354635445;0.3680957438;0.3833920268;0.3970895352;0.4076867315;0.4165702579;0.4253448458;0.434863311;0.4486204513;0.4649510531;0.4820688746;0.4963805587;0.5077244805;0.5167104257;0.5232170563;0.5306466349;0.5409697143;0.5548585474;0.5715871149;0.5870469434;0.6005594924;0.6121972442;0.6207156119;0.6281949133;0.6354022681;0.64337715;0.6561790847;0.6710964529;0.6877550869;0.7017979987;0.7135975674;0.7237851988;0.7320045173;0.7377853697;0.7419342319;0.7467129367;0.7543477159;0.7668209629;0.7806719159;0.7959697793;0.8117495054;0.8242823156;0.8339266152;0.841670204;0.8467285409;0.8466601832;0.8487887669;0.8493197503;0.8514038088;0.8554578594;0.8654597016;0.8788954304;0.8931539767;0.909913852;0.922612058;0.9332210358;0.9428380427;0.9454668351;0.9478930146;0.9454491894;0.9396165869;0.9355576156;0.9323700733;0.9341472136;0.937918952;0.9480471236;0.9603773289;0.9727325525;0.9867021182;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L3_Spot;0.0618733977;0.0676603902;0.0731842722;0.0791780487;0.085032737;0.0906196384;0.0974306984;0.1034144335;0.1088490926;0.1167053001;0.1251706938;0.1319945557;0.1390186165;0.148015902;0.1578329502;0.1650255148;0.1716748224;0.1814098328;0.1927763907;0.2030027796;0.2098682762;0.21789867;0.2303785652;0.243154842;0.2528824105;0.2606289362;0.2690370484;0.2827437866;0.2974806463;0.3085094052;0.3158482449;0.3231239389;0.3347921256;0.3510714598;0.3665108969;0.3767849104;0.3836415177;0.3915547722;0.4037429581;0.42143327;0.4393381221;0.4535186974;0.462006382;0.4677497788;0.4760367858;0.4894177229;0.5085120329;0.5250102547;0.5369630044;0.5452098912;0.5494923476;0.5546163411;0.5674890293;0.5858806401;0.6064034887;0.6244746643;0.6361721101;0.6422368946;0.6441018633;0.6480249691;0.6563331971;0.6715333102;0.6920708952;0.7106273273;0.7254352779;0.7349028228;0.7396943235;0.7400649558;0.7423801132;0.7488859058;0.7627429315;0.7830268691;0.8021249786;0.817411478;0.8292332365;0.8356594358;0.8338883181;0.8325055153;0.8295889675;0.8311029285;0.8394494302;0.8552089368;0.8741404914;0.8923414673;0.9102820313;0.9213583551;0.9280303563;0.9310447551;0.9242712711;0.9173364667;0.9098310833;0.9057701152;0.9123829983;0.9259099773;0.9431240259;0.9590545489;0.9761861868;0.9883615614;0.9951607263;0.9994499727;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L3_Flood;0.0714854097;0.0777523225;0.0833954177;0.0904600296;0.0973492772;0.1026681985;0.1098832447;0.1176664777;0.1234786669;0.1307335696;0.1402395154;0.1489848547;0.1561974735;0.1640111677;0.1746648012;0.1842182042;0.1912457162;0.1993578543;0.2104970316;0.2229061786;0.2318035903;0.2386375325;0.2486922915;0.2621891457;0.2745678691;0.2842963896;0.2912387868;0.3020111649;0.3166504901;0.3303259761;0.3403548159;0.3474832225;0.3558107042;0.3696246536;0.3860234474;0.3995000868;0.4091159515;0.4166846915;0.4250204808;0.439420538;0.4574142129;0.4745795509;0.4865878552;0.4942588007;0.5003283396;0.508674034;0.5241321289;0.5413485203;0.556017238;0.5679254247;0.5752564906;0.5795690239;0.5866245552;0.6001152318;0.6191003189;0.6382347345;0.6529403121;0.6631638483;0.6680636498;0.6716942209;0.6750690953;0.6834815591;0.7004970105;0.7192609531;0.7357458752;0.7483015252;0.7572050781;0.7613939369;0.7636442546;0.7653571087;0.7723309465;0.7868354241;0.8042740302;0.8203959411;0.8338473902;0.8433902964;0.84612672;0.848968406;0.8476680613;0.8462435454;0.8466918571;0.8556390784;0.8708202118;0.8878421628;0.9062886027;0.9189038442;0.9282102215;0.9349769413;0.933405243;0.9303961134;0.9233441922;0.9157002643;0.9146478333;0.9208949876;0.9344269804;0.9488866719;0.9657966901;0.979676154;0.9881745701;0.995800344;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L4_Spot;0.066328486;0.0728696763;0.0783385052;0.0844958501;0.0914624486;0.097241963;0.1035049709;0.1105176182;0.117386944;0.1249070605;0.1330220049;0.1413874719;0.1501592229;0.1584626763;0.1670392361;0.1758246628;0.1847020837;0.1939977324;0.2034931763;0.2137960153;0.2234397177;0.2334413761;0.2439419777;0.2542239649;0.2649125466;0.2765500499;0.2869705389;0.2984054686;0.3094295019;0.3206040724;0.3316302827;0.3426546669;0.3542953729;0.3666125475;0.3780827454;0.3890463025;0.4012738245;0.4143285678;0.4261338259;0.4383366222;0.4511788261;0.4654022289;0.4782084053;0.4896931287;0.5014418552;0.5133119504;0.5262304755;0.5370207578;0.5467479679;0.5582942786;0.5710920751;0.5843865744;0.597343032;0.6077770728;0.619324122;0.6328600262;0.6458157996;0.6582882637;0.667484913;0.677081142;0.6864457375;0.6976186706;0.7107275053;0.7221880827;0.7314826938;0.7394488356;0.7497138946;0.7625332297;0.7762174348;0.7870092528;0.7954331304;0.8024069741;0.8093737267;0.8182693974;0.829141499;0.8402120549;0.8470688546;0.854288074;0.8584631973;0.8635310401;0.8698837598;0.8798864633;0.891717107;0.9020368279;0.9112539726;0.9157994725;0.9198755001;0.9258007744;0.930245102;0.9388154236;0.9452375072;0.9484301871;0.9516597959;0.9525771902;0.9553770314;0.9577398052;0.9635993174;0.9727579752;0.9813576292;0.9915127962;1
Arri_650Plus_TU_L4_Flood;0.0745707824;0.0817642667;0.0878226703;0.0946547006;0.1023386654;0.1086113348;0.1154143995;0.1230703367;0.130298353;0.1384380407;0.1470129989;0.1559244441;0.1652778763;0.1739633772;0.1829936914;0.1921328051;0.2012842737;0.2110389317;0.2207816548;0.2313695871;0.2413701585;0.2516039836;0.2621242572;0.2727715671;0.2836606034;0.2954251833;0.3059758705;0.3175784208;0.3287023611;0.3398573324;0.3508645841;0.3619949279;0.3736290983;0.3859872838;0.3972478376;0.4082515089;0.4206233568;0.4336305051;0.4450532918;0.4572904011;0.4702687873;0.484544056;0.4969470771;0.5081496064;0.5197844047;0.5320472436;0.5446661522;0.5545355016;0.5637511505;0.5757218928;0.5887245804;0.601732135;0.6138475093;0.6234964919;0.6351229156;0.6490740326;0.6621226436;0.6735525466;0.6815617926;0.6906155811;0.7004951678;0.712199559;0.7246978207;0.7350345816;0.7429746804;0.7503643292;0.7611189836;0.7747821434;0.7881492274;0.7974202025;0.8044841653;0.8100988315;0.8173673325;0.827069166;0.8383109877;0.8488342324;0.8539095724;0.8594443563;0.8627125603;0.8675435447;0.875088618;0.8858484789;0.8972077849;0.906067646;0.9136986849;0.917006084;0.920556399;0.9269859961;0.9322921544;0.9419085189;0.9478905422;0.9497564044;0.9520700773;0.951225567;0.9534198954;0.9556880434;0.9626981;0.9733706602;0.9833101577;0.9925356497;1
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Arri_1000Plus_TU_L1_Spot;0.0678901459;0.0744363574;0.0803133472;0.0863179999;0.0932729881;0.0997262036;0.105759511;0.1124609453;0.120149975;0.1277963146;0.1352105884;0.1441191177;0.1537527186;0.16127252;0.169289091;0.1794796986;0.1887761839;0.1966821995;0.2057022483;0.2176029095;0.2279501263;0.2358679152;0.2452664945;0.2576474259;0.2696144301;0.2794115939;0.287668489;0.300059491;0.3139734644;0.3250689786;0.3332905561;0.3423684729;0.3554347395;0.3708846653;0.383075522;0.3908709152;0.3995694835;0.4132188808;0.4291979286;0.4446334397;0.4553247091;0.4637665178;0.473964635;0.4889391073;0.5060692753;0.5201126095;0.5298126922;0.5353124568;0.542194233;0.5557188599;0.5729214593;0.5896170283;0.6026162025;0.6105530552;0.617309786;0.6263014516;0.6399288181;0.6589243915;0.6746587978;0.6874423931;0.6940844739;0.697003196;0.7008134644;0.7112496;0.7275372605;0.7453747305;0.7621397383;0.7740956507;0.781505134;0.7838034027;0.7855947868;0.7917301178;0.8045219593;0.8207873152;0.8371054161;0.8499985201;0.8558648485;0.8608646097;0.8611559633;0.8602555909;0.8608347428;0.8696558243;0.8849562402;0.902193588;0.9201122923;0.931429103;0.9389649017;0.9434995268;0.9388259125;0.9349244958;0.9303647469;0.9291109626;0.9382539988;0.9512235838;0.9669248194;0.9791218778;0.990756558;0.9976485326;0.9996141318;1;0.9969475438
Arri_1000Plus_TU_L1_Flood;0.0751769682;0.0823713051;0.0887264593;0.0954088446;0.103016726;0.1097779911;0.116470737;0.1235338704;0.1317121566;0.1399141548;0.1477669523;0.1571503224;0.1672183222;0.1751722322;0.183548667;0.1940485188;0.2037420036;0.212106824;0.221343683;0.2335218828;0.2441759702;0.252347128;0.2618572996;0.2743501407;0.2865008972;0.2966577933;0.305020213;0.317393435;0.3312649349;0.3424498468;0.3509058031;0.3599977698;0.3729210693;0.3882714275;0.400668751;0.4086133459;0.4172034444;0.4308365525;0.4465231741;0.4618980628;0.4728413535;0.4814261801;0.4916210975;0.5062380142;0.5230000868;0.5369051989;0.5466840018;0.552178819;0.5589998738;0.5720628075;0.5886935295;0.6050075434;0.6179798039;0.6260849826;0.6329696174;0.6416688555;0.6546838775;0.6727480872;0.6878482209;0.7004611513;0.7073319866;0.7103810261;0.7140539131;0.7239420748;0.7392309404;0.7562764542;0.7724537858;0.7842002364;0.7916270514;0.7942489738;0.7960865364;0.8016829643;0.8134515642;0.828750432;0.8439976206;0.8562450083;0.8618662335;0.8671237915;0.8676494554;0.8668229533;0.8671435329;0.875298538;0.8894117358;0.9056560621;0.922596624;0.9336022434;0.9408401323;0.9455978067;0.9414307429;0.9381607249;0.9335976976;0.9318119067;0.9402318275;0.9518190937;0.9666738459;0.9783290772;0.9898730992;0.996996028;0.9992308908;1;0.997277527
Arri_1000Plus_TU_L2_Spot;0.0732902496;0.0803554314;0.0860344983;0.0925924901;0.0999929716;0.1059124125;0.1126635758;0.1198777246;0.1269672558;0.1350905255;0.143387638;0.1519586069;0.1614684597;0.1699107365;0.1783137267;0.187761666;0.1969717591;0.205872206;0.2156476981;0.2266965772;0.2359841599;0.2453246064;0.2566366545;0.2675388541;0.2772067456;0.2883364091;0.3000251308;0.312152012;0.3213918272;0.3316403967;0.3442025313;0.3562999725;0.3662548123;0.3766399399;0.3891124798;0.4023501131;0.4138367394;0.4241696091;0.4347928416;0.4492363438;0.4641294748;0.4767614292;0.4865681073;0.4970702375;0.5107435329;0.5249678448;0.5372972239;0.5452548053;0.5527513827;0.5645240464;0.5792201474;0.594019872;0.6062296714;0.6144325302;0.6234918138;0.6358343018;0.6505932246;0.666208583;0.6766911112;0.6847415261;0.6898138767;0.6966097203;0.7095318464;0.7254012621;0.7395873963;0.7494789825;0.7563084375;0.7611896479;0.7690869176;0.779947982;0.7944383723;0.8095057235;0.8196649008;0.8250604599;0.827928107;0.8299548637;0.833105523;0.8448775769;0.8581961514;0.8712549276;0.8801335981;0.885233753;0.8882718854;0.8897600291;0.8938441234;0.9009986478;0.913064811;0.9278845475;0.9378971086;0.9454448749;0.9462904181;0.9425536989;0.9393477169;0.9369460363;0.9399103618;0.9467371598;0.9605371515;0.9751159654;0.9852199787;0.9947571745;1
Arri_1000Plus_TU_L2_Flood;0.0759960961;0.0833769533;0.0893692927;0.0961601904;0.1038266054;0.1099999719;0.1170607086;0.1245159174;0.13172766;0.1401173151;0.1485641803;0.1573871569;0.1670882152;0.1756610632;0.1843023578;0.1939358142;0.2032611847;0.2122003965;0.2220686785;0.2332500944;0.2424634848;0.2519396836;0.2633645291;0.2742188776;0.2837472699;0.295020191;0.3067606067;0.3187804844;0.3279312543;0.3382083808;0.3507847383;0.3627001914;0.372493524;0.3827952145;0.3954993305;0.4086576597;0.4199318746;0.4300295266;0.4408093548;0.4554071791;0.4701329734;0.4825794203;0.4922157365;0.5027320632;0.5165729089;0.530785243;0.5427882825;0.5503765057;0.55775403;0.5696431843;0.5844933741;0.5991447362;0.6108211979;0.6186985543;0.6277177674;0.6401795122;0.6551214441;0.6705978906;0.6805815913;0.6882989783;0.6930207311;0.6997723309;0.7131060316;0.7290614319;0.7430204448;0.7522924315;0.7586021147;0.7631520277;0.7710587417;0.7824027769;0.7971189827;0.812214425;0.8217666929;0.8264059977;0.8289446385;0.8307470257;0.8341613498;0.8463142409;0.859872927;0.8729223026;0.8811860721;0.8858137303;0.8882560781;0.8893103692;0.8934944617;0.9010092062;0.9135987281;0.9288036219;0.9385146698;0.9455670145;0.9463685546;0.9420363204;0.9382171556;0.9357406492;0.9392052546;0.9464838671;0.9616492787;0.9760571631;0.9863566853;0.994961829;1
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Arri_2000Plus_TU_L1_Spot;0.0670002453;0.0731756421;0.0784066233;0.0868944314;0.0927751731;0.0994792471;0.1083878838;0.1142257206;0.1216522424;0.1298092343;0.1382588395;0.1465612517;0.1553635357;0.1630639256;0.1719442137;0.1803792918;0.1896054029;0.1992610923;0.2093012844;0.219470146;0.2297781508;0.2409639424;0.2507585352;0.262132303;0.2728559432;0.2841744851;0.2963244921;0.3060941551;0.3189620056;0.3304248364;0.3406569277;0.3533068472;0.364412878;0.3770472055;0.3893461029;0.3995546182;0.4121697352;0.4251492251;0.4369359883;0.450371852;0.4637698731;0.4768423175;0.4899643711;0.5023786729;0.514081876;0.5252420669;0.5373627929;0.5484850738;0.5602680961;0.5723280234;0.5845150182;0.5966899772;0.6079122735;0.6201100922;0.6330491021;0.645834341;0.6578774325;0.6692056064;0.6802207168;0.6931209457;0.7031055791;0.7129546509;0.7234280981;0.7341878726;0.7449998251;0.7551755129;0.765920908;0.7763890914;0.7884078973;0.7979620793;0.8080074584;0.8192503919;0.8277067362;0.8384803533;0.8452482399;0.8548921533;0.8580894934;0.8660822173;0.8743487965;0.8788065188;0.8889655108;0.8943845983;0.9021442624;0.913463443;0.9220478481;0.9326734939;0.9421090621;0.9524752333;0.9571585258;0.9607451761;0.9656125449;0.9673562649;0.9621900136;0.9686764189;0.973996622;0.9762697741;0.9805849303;0.989448926;0.9966148924;0.9959348104;1
Arri_2000Plus_TU_L1_Flood;0.0776753967;0.0861312478;0.0931573638;0.1005991538;0.1081903055;0.1162842242;0.1256211932;0.1320788514;0.1390118738;0.1480565117;0.1589335531;0.1689782245;0.1780066142;0.1853905564;0.194099528;0.2055791016;0.2170680816;0.2275283002;0.2365527459;0.2456720187;0.2559785416;0.2682191326;0.2822402944;0.2948917567;0.3056642922;0.3155049164;0.3243816165;0.3365224112;0.3505432279;0.3648953155;0.378071928;0.3894490138;0.3989802635;0.4083156827;0.4182635973;0.4308079367;0.4461235116;0.4620761888;0.4761476195;0.4893739687;0.5000786651;0.5091645465;0.5186054025;0.5296039394;0.5431915291;0.5576739137;0.5732961277;0.5863649019;0.5974392604;0.6080377815;0.6161403827;0.622703827;0.6302727693;0.6405292415;0.6556687588;0.6720919011;0.6879322096;0.7024365108;0.7140660185;0.7250838187;0.7329994067;0.7381840487;0.7421016004;0.7472481605;0.7546440482;0.7641902139;0.7765667931;0.7925701417;0.8077061863;0.8199568611;0.8313122064;0.8413943813;0.848672602;0.8539394182;0.8567558136;0.8589568856;0.8564333952;0.8598776481;0.8650206566;0.871636327;0.8819337321;0.8939136467;0.9068066953;0.9197841365;0.9318422364;0.941160685;0.9489192215;0.9569910547;0.9556703444;0.9577659993;0.9537818591;0.9484946217;0.9437122446;0.9407839611;0.9444404877;0.9488014263;0.9581698645;0.9689447803;0.9797587685;0.9896491323;1
Arri_2000Plus_TU_L2_Spot;0.0849908618;0.0934242262;0.1014674929;0.1099822002;0.1177662719;0.1253492666;0.134697463;0.142342758;0.1505975773;0.159637769;0.169856497;0.1800171878;0.1904933755;0.1997750064;0.209304278;0.2195967056;0.2303571462;0.2413313828;0.2523891267;0.2638755688;0.2752065316;0.2859739007;0.2984220703;0.3110820525;0.3235548365;0.336376107;0.3476023506;0.3600019504;0.3717992313;0.3840503067;0.3968868437;0.4097881732;0.422592282;0.4354193939;0.4470743949;0.4580069137;0.4703430633;0.4838711635;0.4971171506;0.5115211342;0.5255459198;0.5389505797;0.5514061384;0.5627478222;0.5737986877;0.584514454;0.5964193307;0.6080717277;0.6198356646;0.6329621056;0.6450896267;0.6561521142;0.6666775366;0.6766317536;0.6884804157;0.7002021719;0.7113928896;0.7227900287;0.733928084;0.7462221455;0.7568915945;0.7662926634;0.7754789701;0.7842146418;0.7927361138;0.8000912238;0.8075426722;0.8173322426;0.8278594127;0.8369424124;0.8467434591;0.8578046216;0.8671546628;0.8757761628;0.8832203537;0.8903071011;0.8922707743;0.897679717;0.9016222612;0.9043663377;0.9078215986;0.9133081896;0.9208924339;0.9296837496;0.9388365308;0.947253347;0.9554784366;0.9657392633;0.9675925388;0.9739426527;0.9740991903;0.9725736343;0.9725494563;0.9706558513;0.9727960135;0.9746475875;0.9764587147;0.9828435141;0.9875704484;0.993260968;1
Arri_2000Plus_TU_L2_Flood;0.0807115752;0.0894703458;0.0978699426;0.1061627135;0.1134289945;0.1210199135;0.1311422825;0.1390971162;0.1467088486;0.1549488498;0.1652000931;0.1761501872;0.1869601387;0.1956857765;0.2037413337;0.2134131758;0.2247962367;0.236737734;0.2478482829;0.2581276279;0.2673735789;0.2771588324;0.2903191557;0.304245815;0.3171887589;0.3292253492;0.3383798574;0.3483892624;0.3594848121;0.3729902733;0.3875002874;0.4012449413;0.4133500703;0.4242526571;0.4329438741;0.442105278;0.4544771669;0.4699193695;0.4851810575;0.5010043704;0.5146981453;0.5261441518;0.5357855811;0.544368079;0.5538931202;0.5652343121;0.5800344998;0.594509798;0.6080847351;0.6214793674;0.6325468091;0.6411901792;0.6484444601;0.6555268879;0.6658492166;0.6782501983;0.692181294;0.7073740594;0.7211370925;0.7347050672;0.7453691595;0.7534360406;0.7599210124;0.7654489258;0.770723779;0.7757173269;0.7824415027;0.7943932032;0.8082257223;0.8210994055;0.8341906965;0.8468468523;0.8570115297;0.8650534328;0.871078191;0.875781009;0.8748740527;0.8774277218;0.8791833208;0.8806829211;0.8852428769;0.8937849453;0.905407754;0.9185606003;0.9326556734;0.9441852595;0.9544661939;0.9655744567;0.9672118435;0.9728555981;0.9714115779;0.9684882194;0.9654110348;0.9608515281;0.9615879829;0.9613272893;0.9640521407;0.9712406305;0.9792932863;0.9894410019;1
```

I have tried to use various combinations of `dtype` and `unpack=True` without too much success so far.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` is the most powerful numpy csv reader. You might have to skip the `;;;` lines.  With `dtype=None` you'll get a 1d structured array.

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes indeed, `np.recfromcsv` wraps it. So far, the only successful go I had at this is to transpose the file before reading. Looking at the `np.genfromtxt` code, it seems like transposing is done a the very end and I'm not really sure how it plays out with *recarrays*.

Comment: `genfromtxt` creates one field for each column.  But if you prefer, it should be easy to read the file line by line, spliting on `;` and using the 1st string as some sort of header.  `csv` with many rows and a few columns seem to be more common.

Comment: Describing from what you get with `genfromtxt` (or `recfromcsv`) might help.  Better yet make a smaller demo text along with the desired result.  I ran `genfromtxt` on a copy-n-paste and got an array with (20,) shape and 102 fields.  All fields `f8` except the first.

Comment: You usually get best response on SO with debugging questions.  They will have code, working or not, small sample inputs, and a clear description of the error, whether it is error message with traceback, or output that does not match the desired.  Good answers tend to follow the same pattern - code with a small working example.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better choice to read your data is not *Numpy* but *Pandas*.
The basic reasons are that:

- *Numpy* arrays shoud have same type of each element,
- but your first column is rather a "sample name" (string),
- and in the result (transposed) array it should be the **index** column
  (what is supported only in *Pandas*),
- leaving all other column of *float* type.

So to read your data (so far without any transposition) use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()
```

Note the final *dropna()* to drop rows with *NaN*, resulting from
rows containing only semi-colons.

Then, to get your tranposed array, run:

```
result = df.T
```

The result (limited to initial columns and rows) is:

```
Wavelength(nm)  Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Spot  Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Flood  Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Spot  Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Flood
380                            0.064942                  0.070919                 0.070375                  0.074892
384                            0.071336                  0.078001                 0.077249                  0.082744
388                            0.076722                  0.083827                 0.082296                  0.088379
392                            0.082816                  0.090440                 0.088213                  0.094135
396                            0.089634                  0.097831                 0.095796                  0.101840
```

Note that *Wavelength(nm)* is the name of the index column and each other
(regular) column has the sample name as its name.

Or you can do the whole job in one go, running:

```
result = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep=';', index_col=0).dropna().T
```

If you wish, you can take the underying *Numpy* array for further processing,
running:

```
result2 = result.values
```

But in this case you loose column names and row indices.
Such an array has:

- row indices as consecutive integers (starting from 0), instead of
  sample names,
- column indices also as consecutive integers, instead of vawelengths.

Your choice which representation to choose.

Comment: `numpy` has `structured arrays` (or `recarray`) which can have differing dtype for each `field`, the equivalent of a DataFrame with differing dtypes in each column.  In fact `df.to_records` (or something like that) produces such an array.  `pandas` though may handle this transpose more gracefully.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use Pandas for that, it is adding a dependency on our library that I don't really want to have as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward use of `genfromtxt`:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=';', dtype=None, encoding=None)
In [113]: data.shape
Out[113]: (20,)
In [115]: len(data.dtype.fields)
Out[115]: 102
```

Since just the first field is string, and the rest float, it might be better to load them separately:

```
In [116]: labels = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=';', dtype=None, encoding=None, usecols=(0,))
In [117]: labels
Out[117]: 
array(['Wavelength(nm)', '', 'Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Spot',
       'Arri_650Plus_TU_L1_Flood', 'Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Spot',
       'Arri_650Plus_TU_L2_Flood', 'Arri_650Plus_TU_L3_Spot',
       'Arri_650Plus_TU_L3_Flood', 'Arri_650Plus_TU_L4_Spot',
       'Arri_650Plus_TU_L4_Flood', '', 'Arri_1000Plus_TU_L1_Spot',
       'Arri_1000Plus_TU_L1_Flood', 'Arri_1000Plus_TU_L2_Spot',
       'Arri_1000Plus_TU_L2_Flood', '', 'Arri_2000Plus_TU_L1_Spot',
       'Arri_2000Plus_TU_L1_Flood', 'Arri_2000Plus_TU_L2_Spot',
       'Arri_2000Plus_TU_L2_Flood'], dtype='<U25')
In [118]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter=';', dtype=None, encoding=None, usecols=range(1
     ...: ,102))
In [119]: data.dtype
Out[119]: dtype('float64')
In [120]: data.shape
Out[120]: (20, 101)
```

(The all `;` rows are filled with `nan`.)

One could make a structured array using the `labels` as field names, but..., I wonder if that is the most useful array.  The homogeneous `data` array may be better for some tasks, for example calculations across the 20 "fields".

`unpack` returns a list, one array per column of the regular data.  With version 1.20 I get one array of the labels, and 101 arrays of the numeric values, all with (20,) shape.

Comment: Thanks! My take away is that it is not really doable in one shot, I will probably open an issue on the Numpy repo to discuss about it. I ended up transposing the file upfront: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/318a38120b1bac5325d6d072862b4a99b5988dab/colour/io/tabular.py#L116